# What exactly is OSX doing during the "Optimizing system" step of software installation?

Tags: macos, installation, performance

I've seen "Optimizing system for installed software" as a quite lengthy step during both Software Update's installations and regular installer-based app installs. What exactly is the system optimizing during this step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this is [prebinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prebinding), which speeds up shared object loading at runtime.